# What does this expression with universal quantifier mean?

Tags: universal, quantifiers, first-order-logic

I just encounter this expression, and since I've never learned universal quantifier before so I have no idea what does this mean, can anyone explain this to me thanks.

```
∀α.α → α
```

I know it is a universal quantifier but i don't know how it works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a symbolic logic question, and should be migrated to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the identity.  Please don't take my word on this, it has been many years since I have considered universal quantifiers

Answer (score 0):

The WFF (well-formed formula) says, for all a, if a, then a.

That's quite tautological, really: even a tautog could see that.

Comment: thanks, but the for all a is the first a or the second a